# Listing gulp-load-plugins loaded

Tags: gulp, gulp-load-plugins

I'm using the `gulp-load-plugins`, and I'm trying to print the loaded plugins:
        `console.log(JSON.stringify(plugins));`
but it only prints `{}`.

Is there anyway to print the loaded plugins and the names assigned to the plugins.

UPDATE:
Got it working:

1. Set lazy loading to false
2. add `console.log(plugins);` after the runnung task

   `var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')({lazy:false});`
   `...`
   `gulp.task('default', ['styles']);`
   `console.log(plugins);`

Comment: you can answer your question below :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the code of the plugins, you can see that the properties of the object returned are defined with

```
Object.defineProperty()
```

And this method allow to set not enumerable properties.
So the properties you are looking for don't appear.

I agree that this is "bizarre" as it would help the developper to trace which plugin are actually available.